# Chrome manifest v3: runtime.lastError specify 'func' and 'files'?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm searching for a solution everywhere and I can't find nothing about this error. I'm trying to "update" a Chrome extension to manifest v3 and I get this error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Exactly one of 'func' and 'files' must be specified
```

Does somebody have an idea on what can I do to solve this? Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Extension_Name",
    "description": "Extension_Desc",
    "version": "5.0",
    "icons": {
        "16": "/images/image16.png",
        "48": "/images/image48.png",
        "128": "/images/image128.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://example.com/*"
    ]
}
```

And here is my popup.html, that is referenced in the error (but without a specific line, only popup.html:0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://example.com">
    <title>Extension Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Ghost</h2>
    <form name ="form" id="login_form" action="#">
        <input type="text" id="mdp" placeholder="Password"/>
        <input type ="button" name="submit" value="Login" id="login"/>
    </form>
    
    <button id="logout">Logout</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that unsafe-eval is not supported in manifest v3, but I will deal with this error later. If I delete unsafe-eval, the other error remains, so the two are not linked.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error refers to chrome.scripting.executeScript so check your code and conform it to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I watched the documentation and I had to specify the file name in the executeScript().

Comment: It'd be helpful for people with the same problem if you add an answer with the old and new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the error is solved by adding "files" in the executeScript() function. Before I had:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                {
                    target: {tabId: tab.id},
                    function: functionToExecute()
                })
```

The solution found is:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                {
                    target: {tabId: tab.id},
                    files: ['popup.js'],
                    function: functionToExecute()
                })
```

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: you don't need to specify the file, the keyword to specify a function to execute is `func` not `function`.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried earlier to add parameters and reverted that, but I forgot to remove the `()` at the end of the function after `func:`. removing these will fix the `func` error as well.